# How many windows services should I create?

Tags: windows-services

I have a web app (ASP.NET). There are some scheduled tasks and background tasks that need to be run regularly (for example email queue, search indexer...). My question is should I create a windows service to handle all those jobs, or separate ones for each job? What is best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: As an administrator, I would stab you for adding N jobs to Windows Services...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create separate services for each job. This will help if any functionality related to a job causes problem and stops the service it won't affect the other job.